# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression

Tags: swift

I want to divide difference data into 60 and print it as double numbers. When I print it as a string, it does not appear to be a fraction of the number. I get this problem when I print the number "n" . What should I do?

My mistake: the compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

```
if let date = formatter.date(from: receivedTimeString) {
    let receivedTimeHoursMinutes = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date) * 60
    let receivedTimeMinutes = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date)
    let totalreceivedTimeMinutes = receivedTimeHoursMinutes + receivedTimeMinutes

    let todayHoursMinutes = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()) * 60
    let todayMinutes = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())
    let todayTimeMinutes = todayHoursMinutes + todayMinutes

    let difference = todayTimeMinutes - totalreceivedTimeMinutes
    let str = String(difference)

    switch true {
    case difference > 60:
        let deger = String(difference / 60)
        guard let n = NumberFormatter().number(from: deger) else { return }

        print("deger", deger)
        self.labelTimerFarkSonuc.text = (n) + (" ") + ("Saattir") + (" ") + (durum)
    case difference == 0:
        self.labelTimerFarkSonuc.text = (n) + (" ") + ("Dakikadır")  + (" ") + (durum)
    case difference < 60:
        self.labelTimerFarkSonuc.text = (n) + (" ") + ("Dakikadır")  + (" ") + (durum)
    default:
        self.labelTimerFarkSonuc.text = (n) + (" ") + ("Dakikadır")  + (" ") + (durum)
    }
```

Comment: You don't need any of the brackets in `(n) + (" ") + ("Dakikadır")  + (" ") + (durum)`. They just add visual noise. String interpolation looks nicer (in this case), too: `"\(n) Dakikadır \(durum)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i had understood your question correctly,

If you want to have result of following code as decimal fraction,

```
let deger = String(difference / 60) // Dividing by INT will not give fractions.
```

Change it to following.

```
let deger = String(difference / 60.0)
```

Comment: Error code: Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double'

Comment: It is bcoz difference is INT. Please cast it to double and try

Comment: For example, when I do the splitting process in the form of 5.966666666612321 gives output. How can I do that I just want to write 5.96? @Anand

Comment: Please see NumberFormatter options like minimum fraction digits etc. it is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter

Comment: let degerdakika = String(format: "%.2f", (Double(difference) / 60.0))
thanks